# How to create a custom "ExpectedException" junit rule?

Tags: java, junit

I need to create a Rule to check for exceptions with customized messages. Below is my attempt, but this is not quite correct since I am simply using methods from the standard "ExpectedException". How to do it right?

```
public class CustomExpectedExceptionRule implements TestRule {
    private final ExpectedException delegate = ExpectedException.none();

    public static CustomExpectedExceptionRule none() {
        return new CustomExpectedExceptionRule();
    }

    private CustomExpectedExceptionRule() {
    }

    public void expect(Class<? extends Throwable> type) {
        delegate.expect(type);
    }

    public void expectMessage(String message) {
        delegate.expectMessage(message);
    }

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return delegate.apply(base, description);
    }
```

Now I'm trying something like that:

```
 private final ExpectedException expectedException = ExpectedException.none();
    private Object exception;
    private String expectedMessage;

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                expectedException.expect((Class<? extends Throwable>) exception);
                expectedException.expectMessage(expectedMessage);
                base.evaluate();
            }
        };
    }

    public void expectedMessage(String expectedMessage) {
        this.expectedMessage = expectedMessage;
    }

    public void expectedException(Object exception) {
        this.exception = exception;
    }
```

But this test does not work where the exception is thrown does not pass, though all fields here are passed.
How do I remake it in the correct form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the requirement, in your tests you need to:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Rule 
    ExpectedException expExc = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void throwsNothing() {
        // "normal tests" not affected.
    }

    @Test
    public void throwsExceptionWithSpecificTypeAndMessage() {
       expExc.expect(MyCustomException.class);
       expExc.expectMessage("substring, that passes test");// other matchers possible
       // do something that (is expected to) raise(s) 
       // MyCustomException("substring, that passes test").
    }
}
```

..where `MyCustomException.class` is a custom exception class (the lowest possible in inheritance hierarchy, which you want to "pass"), and `substring, that passes test` the (part of) the message, which you want to "pass".

Introducing a custom `TestRule` saves you `1 line/Test`. In this simple case I would recommend you, not to implement the interface but extend `ExternalResource` (, [see here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/rules#externalresource-rules))):

```
class CustomExpectedException extends ExternalResource /*implements (!) TestRule*/ {

    private ExpectedException expExc = ExpectedException.none();

    /* Parameterize the message and also the class, if it fits your needs, 
     * alternatively && additionally implement defaults/constants/more methods.*/
    public void myExpect(String substr) {
        expExc.expect(MyCustomException.class);
        expExc.expectMessage(substr);// other matchers possible
    }
}
```

...and then use it like:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Rule 
    CustomExpectedException expExc = new CustomExpectedException();
    ...
    @Test
    public void throwsExceptionWithSpecificTypeAndMessage() {
       expExc.myExpect("substring, that passes test");
      // do something...
    }
}
```

---

A rule-less approach(, [see here](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-2-expected-exception-test/)) :

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void throwsExceptionWithSpecificTypeAndMessage() {
        try { // !
            // do something ...
            // after that, fail the test:
            org.junit.Assert.fail("expected exception!");
        } catch (Exception exc) { // ! here i would recommend "the highest possible Exception" (in inheritance hierarchy) ...even better <code>Throwable</code>.
           // this code can be moved to a (static) util method:
           if (exc instanceof MyCustomException) {
               // make assertions on ((MyCustomException) exc).getMessage();
           } else {
               org.junit.Assert.fail("UNexpected exception!");
               // or rethrow:
               // throw exc;
           }
        }          
    }
}
```